# PHP cURL works when i enter URL Directly but not work its in a variable

Tags: php, curl

I have a really weird problem and its something that ive done im assuming but i can't understand why.

I've managed to put this script together based on several other scripts. My PHP/cURL knowledge is very minimal.

The script is for downloading a long list of files onto my PC. It will check if the file already exists and if it does exist download the next one. (Ive removed the site name URL for privacy reasons)

```
    <?php
    set_time_limit(0);

    function curlOpen($url){
        $cookie="cookie.txt";
        $curl = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Firefox/3.0.5');
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);

        $page = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
        return $page;
    }

    $n64List = curlOpen("http://www.site-name.com/Game/List-All-Titles/9");

    //Get Game Name
    $pattern_gameName = '#href="(.*?)">(.*?)<\/a><\/td><\/tr><tr><td bgcolor#';
    preg_match_all($pattern_gameName,$n64List,$match_gameName);


    for($i=0, $count = count($match_gameName[2]);$i<$count;$i++) {
      $filePath = "N64/".$match_gameName[2][$i].".zip";
      if(!file_exists($filePath)) {
        $gameName = $match_gameName[2][$i];
        $gameUrl = $match_gameName[1][$i];
        break;    
      }
    }


    $url = curlOpen("http://www.site-name.com".$gameUrl."-download");
    $pattern = '#<a href="(.*?)" id="download-link">#';
    preg_match($pattern,$url,$match);

    $download1 =  "http://www.site-name.com".$match[1]."";    
    $download = "http://www.site-name.com/get-download.php?gid=39915&token=4e48678bd20bdd39086777b1fe6aafc1&mirror_available=true";

    $cookie="cookie.txt";
    $fp = fopen (dirname(__FILE__) . "/test.zip", 'w+');//This is the file where we save the    information
    $ch = curl_init(str_replace(" ","%20",$download1));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 150);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp); // write curl response to file
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:7.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.0.12011-10-16 20:23:00");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://www.site-name.com".$gameUrl."-download"); 

    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    ?>
```

The 2 Variables $download and $download1 both contain exactly the same content, The both have the URL to the file.

If i edit this line:

```
$ch = curl_init(str_replace(" ","%20",$download1));
```

It works fine with the download URL in $download1 But won't work if i use $download

Really doesn't make sense as they have identical content...

Anyone have any ideas as its really annoying me.

Thanks

Comment: What does `var_dump($download === $download1)` say?

Comment: I just figured it out, Its because the $download1 has &amp; instead of & i only noticed it after viewing source, appreciate your help anyway.

Comment: You're welcome. Sometimes the answer to 'why is it not working' is the question 'is my assumption right?' ;)